# How to detect the exact browser django

Tags: python, django

I have tried using request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
for detecting the browser . 
But this returns the type of browsers list when i tested on

chrome:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36

instead of just returning chrome
and similarly on :

edge:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299

mozilla:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0

** I am not able to get the pattern in which it is returning values. 
Can anyone tell the way by which i could get the browser name

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with Django. What you want is a User Agent string database that will map a User Agent string to a reasonable browser family. However, as I'm sure many other web developers will tell you, trying to guess the browser from the UA string is mostly an exercise in vain.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in reading about why the user agent string is such a mess: [reddit post `why_every_user_agent_string_start_with_mozilla`](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/6g7iyz/why_every_user_agent_string_start_with_mozilla/) and [direct link to the article](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use request object for the same:

```
request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

also there is a package for that : `django-user-agents`

Comment: request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] returns list of browsers